# Alteryx MD5_ASCII() function equivalent solution in Python

Tags: python, encoding, md5, hashlib, alteryx

I'm not able to match the results of an MD5_ASCII() function in my Python program. Unfortunately I can't post the exact input string and results so please bear with me.

My code in Python looks something like this:

```
import hashlib

str_text = "SV6*123*TT"
str_hashed_1 = hashlib.md5(str_text.encode()).hexidigest()
```

The produced string does not match the MD5_ASCII() output. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually found the issue. There was nothing wrong with the hashing function, the issue was with the input itself.